# err_cert_authority_invalid intermittently on multiple browsers and multiple sites

Tags: ssl-certificate

Recently I have had a rather disturbing issue. Seemingly at random I get err_cert_authority_invalid errors from various websites which goes away after about 15 minutes. This is particularly bad for me because one of them is discordapp.com and the discord application suffers the same problem shutting down my ability to use discord at all. The nvidia driver site also had the same problem. I tried this on Chrome, Firefox, and Edge and got the same issue with all three browsers. As far as I know the only cause for this error is when a certificate is signed by an untrusted authority.

Upon examining the certificate data, this is what I discovered:

*During the issue*

- Issuer: Cisco
- Issued to: discord.com
- Expiry: duration of the cert is only about five days but the current date is always within that five day range

*After the issue passes*

- Issuer: COMODO
- Issued to: ssl764977.cloudflaressl.com
- Expiry: From May 2020 to End of November 2020

As far as I can tell, they aren't self-signed because issuer and issued-to are different. The expiration date has not passed. The only conclusion is that the issuer isn't trusted. Sadly I don't remember the before/after for the nvidia site (when it happens again, I'll get screenshots).

I was concerned that I may have a virus so I made sure that wasn't the case by doing a full reformat of my computer (it was due for one anyway). The issue still arises. Furthermore, I tried using my laptop and it doesn't experience this issue, although I only tried my laptop for a short time so maybe this intermittent problem just didn't trigger. The only thing I can think of that can be causing this is a Windows security update, but then you would think my google fu would find evidence of others experiencing the same problem right now, which it doesn't. Although there are countless similar issues from various times over decades. How can I discover the source of this problem in an effort to fix it? The problem is occurring a couple of times each day now.

For reference:

- Windows 10 x64 build 1909 (No updates required)
- Chrome 86.0.4240.111
- Firefox 82.0
- Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0

I have included screenshots of the traceroutes and certs [here](https://imgur.com/a/2WlHgdH)

Edit 1: Changed causes for error to only the one the comments suggested was the problem.

Edit 2: Included link with screenshots

Comment: Your 2 (expiry) does NOT cause this error, and your 1 is redundant: a self-signed cert for a website is issued by the website, and no website is a trusted CA, so a website's self-signed cert is not issued by a trusted CA. Cisco is not a CA, so if you are seeing a cert issued by Cisco it means your connection is going through (aka intercepted by) a Cisco device such as https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/firepower/610/configuration/guide/fpmc-config-guide-v61/understanding_traffic_decryption.html#id_101163 ...

Comment: ... If you are connected through a normal residential ISP I would expect this not to _vary_ -- depending on what country you are in they might have interception, but if so it would be constant. But if you are using a business or organization network, or a largish shared network like a school/college, hotel, or apartment building, they might well have mutiple network connections that work differently and you might get different ones at different times. You could try comparing `traceroute` but don't rely on it; many boxes nowadays try to be 'transparent' to IP routing.

Comment: This is at a residential property

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the cuplrit. It is my workplace VPN, I forgot to disable it because it just sits hidden in my system tray and it was wreaking havoc with my DNS lookups.